# Firebase RISC API integration

Tags: firebase, google-identity

I'm using sign in with google via firebase, but I'd like to register a custom receiver (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#register_your_receiver) to detect Security Events (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#handle_events)

As reported in the errors table here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#error_codes

> 403   "Existing stream configuration does not have spec-compliant
> delivery method for RISC." -> "Your Google Cloud project must already
> have a RISC configuration. If you are using Firebase and have Google
> Sign-In enabled, then Firebase will be managing RISC for your project;
> you will not be able to create a custom configuration. If you are not
> using Google Sign-In for your Firebase project, please disable it, and
> then try to update again after an hour."

I undestand that  Firebase manage RISC for my project. Does it means that I cannot detect security events with custom receiver?
Is there any way I can intercept these events via Firebase?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to intercept those events? They are really complicated operations and Google will do a job for you. Your user will be able to log in to your app when he will take control lover his Gmail account, for example. Sometimes it's not enough just prevent sign-in by provider. Someone might know user password and user might have same password in your application.

Comment: Cause I need to know when the user revoke permission to my app from google account management, in order to delete user data in my system

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Firebase support team and they said that unfortunately, at the moment, there's no way to intercept these events using Firebase Authentication, it could be a new feature.